# When is a system called linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, linear-control

In real time systems / control engineering we have to solve exercises like this:

> Check if the following systems are linear:
>
> 1) $0.2\ddot{x}(t) - (t^2 + 2t -1) x(t) = 3 w(t)$
>
> 2) $\ddot{x}(t) + \dot{x}(t) + x(t) = w(t)$

A student created the following solution:

> 1) $$\begin{align}&0.2 \frac{d^2 (h x_1 (t) + l x_2(t))}{d t^2} - (t^2 +2t-1)(h x_1(t) + l x_2(t))\\
> =&0.2 h \ddot{x_1}(t) - (t^2 + 2t-1) h x_1(t) + 0.2 l \ddot{x}_2(t) - (t^2 + 2t-1) l x_2(t)\\
> =& h w_1(t) + l w_2(t) \Rightarrow \text{linear}\end{align}$$
>
> 2) not linear because of +1
>
> see Laplace: $s^2 X(s) + s X(s) + X(s) + \frac{1}{s} = W(1) \Rightarrow \frac{X(s)}{W(s)} = \frac{1}{s^2 + s +1} - \frac{1}{s(s^2 + s + 1) W(s)} \Rightarrow$ no transfer function $\Rightarrow$ not linear.

Could somebody please explain how one can decide for arbitrary systems if they are linear?

I don't understand the steps which were done in (1) either.

Comment: Yep transfer function is the english word. Överföringsfunktion på svenska.

Comment: This is why students of this engineering field should also take linear algebra.

Comment: At my local university linear algebra is mandatory for all students mastering in control engineering I think. Maybe it is given as an independent course in this case?

Comment: @HansEngler I don't see how this comment helps. I did have Linear Algebra classes and I was good in that. However, the solutions suggest that there is an implicit dependance of $x$ on $w$  or a different definition of "linear". I should probably have asked this question on http://engineering.stackexchange.com/, but I thought it was something specific to differential equations. Or a well known use case of differential equations. I assumed that because there is no explanation in any of the material we were given in this lecture.

Comment: The system is linear if it can be written as a first order system of the form $\dot y(t) = A(t)y(t) + F(t)$ where $A(t)$ is a matrix valued function. Both examples have this property.

Comment: What is $w(t)$? Also, you only apply transfer function if the system is linear but not vise versa.

Answer (score 2):

A *function* $L$ acting on some collection of "vectors" is called linear if for any scalar $c$ and two "vectors" $x_1,x_2$, we have $L(cx_1+x_2)=cL(x_1)+L(x_2)$. In other words, $L$ commutes with scalar multiplication and distributes over vector addition. In differential equations these are usually functions themselves, but I call them "vectors" because they are elements of some vector space, which means that many of the tools from linear algebra are applicable in this setting.

An *equation* is called linear if it is of the form $Lx=y$ for some linear function $L$, some unknown "vector" $x$, and some known "vector" $y$ (which, because it's known, cannot have any explicit dependence on $x$).

Here, unless $w$ implicitly depends on $x$ in some fashion that you haven't specified, both of your equations are linear. That's because differentiation is linear, multiplication by a fixed function of $t$ is linear, and sums of linear functions are linear.

I don't really understand why you would need to calculate the transfer function to determine if your equation is linear or not.

Answer (score 1):

All differential equations that can be written on the form
$$f_0(t)x(t)+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n f_j (t)\frac{\mathrm{d}^jx(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^j} = g(t) $$
are linear ordinary differential equations.

If $f_0(t),f_1(t),...,f_n(t)$ are all constant (with respect to $t$), we call it a differential equation with constant coefficients. If $g(t)$ is identical to $0$, then we call the differential equation for *homogeneous*, otherwise *inhomogeneous*/*nonhomogeneous*. If $f_n(t)$ is not identical to $0$ we call the differential equation to be of order $n$.

**Example 1.**

We have the differential equation
$$0.2 \cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2} - (t^2+2t-1) x(t) = 3w(t).$$

This is an inhomogeneous, linear ordinary differential equation (of order $2$) with variable coefficients. This is because it is of the given form with

$$f_0(t) = -(t^2+2t-1),\quad f_1(t) = 0,\quad f_2(t) = 0.2 $$
and $g(t) = 3w(t).$

**Example 2.**
We have the differential equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} + x(t) = w(t).$$

This is an inhomogenous, linear ordinary differential equation (of order $2$) with constant variables, because it is of the given form and 
$f_0(t) = f_1(t) = f_2(t) = 1$
are constants, and $g(t) = w(t)$.

Therefore we conclude that both of the given differential equations are linear.